# Passing the standard output of function A as the argument of function B in C++

Tags: c++, pipe, cout

I'm starting C++ and I'd like to code a linker

I first did a tokenizer executable that takes as an input a file and print in the standard output the list of its tokens

```
%./tokenizer input_file
Token 1 : 3
Token 2 : X
token 3 : 10
etc
...
```

Then, I programmed a linker executable that takes as an input a token file and print in the standard output the symbol table and memory map.

```
%./tokenizer input_file > temp
%./linker temp
Symbol Table :
X=10
etc
...

Memory Map :
000: 1002
etc
...
```

Now, my goal is to have a single executable that takes the input file "INPUT" and prints in the standard output the symbol table and memory map. It is important for me to respect this format.

I want :

```
%./linker input_file
Symbol Table :
X=10
etc
...

Memory Map :
000: 1002
etc
...
```

For now, I've copied the main() of the tokenizer inside the .cc of the linker (under a different name of course) but I don't know what to do next.

For example I'd like my code to basically look like : (i precise ifstream because that's how I wrote my code so it would help me to keep it that way)

```
int getTokens(char* file[]) {
   string token;
   ifstream _file (file);
   doStuff(_file);
   ....
   cout << token << endl;
   ....
}
int main(int argc, char argv*[]) {
   char* input_file[] = argv[1];
   ifstream tokenFile = convertCoutToIFSTREAM(getTokens(input_file))
   doOtherStuff(tokenFile);
   ...
   cout << linkResults << endl;
```

I could make a shell script where I first run the tokenizer, saves its output in a file then run the linker on it but I'd like to find a way where I do not have to create a file in between.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: i thik what you are looking for is stringstream. this lets you stream to a string just like it was a file or stdout and then read it back just like it was an input file or stdin. see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stringstream-c-applications/

Comment: What you seem to be creating is not so much a linker as a compiler. A compiler takes a list of source tokens and translates it into some other code (straight to target machine code, assembly code, or some other intermediate code).

Comment: It would be helpful to write `doStuff` and `doOtherStuff` as `bool doStuff(std::istream & in)` so you can pass any sort of stream to them.

Comment: You don't want to do this. You want to pass around the actual data, not a string representation of it that the recipient has to re-parse. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way would be to use streams

You have to change

```
void getTokens(char* file[]) {
   string token;
   ifstream _file (file);
   doStuff(_file);
   // ....
   cout << token << endl;
   // ....
}
```

into

```
void getTokens(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) {
   doStuff(in);
   // ....
   out << token << endl;
   // ....
}
```

And then you can chain the call. (not a real *pipe*, as whole function has to be finished before the other begins).

```
void tokenizer(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out);
void linker(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    assert(argc > 1);
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    std::stringstream ss;
    tokenizer(in, ss);
    linker(ss, std::cout);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/aYPgD7)

Comment: Your answer was clear and concise, you even kept the ifstream as I was hoping for, and you provided a code example of your answer, you sir have a pure heart, may fortune smile on you Jarod. (And your answer worked of course, thanks a lot !)